# Select Query Running slowly for a particular table

Tags: sql-server

In my table, I have more than 300 records in a table.

If, for example, I run

```
select top 200 * from tablename
```

it runs fast. But if I run

`select top 301 * from tablename`

It's executing for a long time.....

Also, I can't run the following query at all:

`select * from tablename`

...it is too slow...

I want to the delete the records after 301 in that table.

Comment: 300 records? erm, that's not many!

Comment: Sounds like you may be being blocked by an open transaction (uncommitted insert/update/delete) locking at least one row between `200` and `301` Does 
`select top 301 * from tablename with (nolock)` return fast?

Comment: or how to delete after the 301 records

Answer (score 1):

How wide is your table?  What's the table definition look like?

If you have an identity column you could just run this:

```
delete from dbo.Table where TableID>301
```